# Error trying to create a stored procedure in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Error while trying to create mysql stored procedure.Here is stored procedure

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE `crossqueue_bw`.`pr_SaveProfile`(IN vProfileId INT)

    BEGIN
        IF SELECT COUNT(ProfileId) FROM tblprofile WHERE ProfileId=vProfileId > 0 THEN

        ELSE

        END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the error

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(ProfileId) from tblprofile where ProfileId=vProfileId > 0 then

' at line 6
```

**Update::**

tried with this query

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE `crossqueue_bw`.`pr_SaveProfile`(IN vProfileId INT)

    BEGIN
        DECLARE v_count INT;
        v_count = SELECT COUNT(ProfileId) FROM tblprofile WHERE ProfileId=vProfileId;
        IF v_count > 0 THEN

        ELSE

        END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the error

```
    Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= SELECT COUNT(ProfileId) FROM tblprofile WHERE ProfileId=vProfileId;
        if v_cou' at line 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually dere were 2 errors one as reported by @Sashi the missing parenthesis and other was that atleast one condition should be there inside the if and else portion else it will show error.

Here is the working code

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE `crossqueue_bw`.`pr_SavePrssosssfile`(IN vProfileId INT)

    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(ProfileId) FROM tblprofile WHERE ProfileId=vProfileId) > 0 THEN
        SET @q=0;
        ELSE
        SET @q=0;
        END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SP use:

```
 DECLARE v_count int;

    set v_count := (SELECT COUNT(ProfileId) FROM tblprofile WHERE ProfileId=vProfileId);

    IF (v_count > 0) THEN
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20579/discussion-between-sashi-kant-and-jade)